# The image is not rendering in this react component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAC78.png)

[list component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mySkr.png)

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4JHJ.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxif3.png)

I don't know what is wrong, except image elements are rendered

Comment: Please provide full code with codesandbox and also add height and width to image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your list component requires props named `imag`, but you pass a prop named `image`.